# Why to paint more that one object using its attributes, the second object use the previous object values?

Tags: java, swing, object, attributes, awt

I did a code from an object with its attributes, its attributes are used to paint a component, to time of create other object from the same class, at method: paint(Graphics g), is used the value of previous created object.

**Object class - extends a JPanel**

```
public RoundedPanel(int x){
    this.x = x; 

    System.out.println(x);
} // End of builder

public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE); 
    g.fillRect(x, 0, 100, 100); 

    System.out.println(x); 

    setBounds(x, 0, 100, 100); 
    setBackground(0, 0, 0, 0); 
} // End of method - paint
```

**Use of RoundedPanel**

```
RoundedPanel firstPanel = new RoundedPanel(4),
             secondPanel = new RoundedPanel(0);
```

I set a System.out.println("x: " + x) message at builder, and at paint method, to know the attribute values, and, at the builder the values are corrects, but at the paint method, the values are from the first object:

Prints:

Builder: 
    first object x: 4,
    second object x: 0.

Paint: 
    first object x: 4,
    second object x: 4.

I expect that at paint the x values are, first: 4, second: 0

Comment: This can has different reasons, hard to tell with the currently posted code snippet. Please check the site "[mcve]" and update your code here, so we analyze your code.

Comment: @Tom I have modified the answer, I hope that'll help

Comment: Paint methods are for drawing.  They can be called many times by the system, for many reasons.  You can read a component’s state in a paint method, but you should never modify the state of the component in a paint method.  Do not change its bounds or its background or any other attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause was that I used the own methods of the class at paint(Graphics g), setBounds() and setBackground(), I think that making that, it repainting. I removed that methods and it function.

Comment: *"setBounds() and setBackground()"* Will both cause changes to a component which will, in turn, trigger a `repaint()` in an infinite loop.